# Tabbed Page OnAppearing()

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a Tabbed Page Xamarin Form application that I am trying to customize. I am migrating from an IOs only app to all platforms. In iOS there are a couple function that I used ViewDidDisappear(), ViewDidAppear() and ViewDidLoad();

The application today loads the tabbed page as follows:

```
{
    Children.Add(new MyPage1());
    Children.Add(new MyPage2());
    Children.Add(new MyPage3());
    Children.Add(new MyPage4());
}
```

Each of the child pages are declared as follows all inheriting from ContentPage.

```
class MyPage1: ContentPage
{
        …
        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            Content = SomeContentPage;
        }
}
```

The problem that I am running into is that the OnAppearing() is called for all pages when only MyPage1 is currently displayed. I need to know when each child page is loaded.

I have read about message center but I am not sure how to implement it in this particular case. Would the message center be the best solution for this?

How do I implement a solution that will allow me to know which of the four pages is displayed?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you managed to resolve it?

Comment: Hi, this is a known bug and fixed in the latest pre-release

Comment: So your problem is OnAppearing method being called more than once right?

Comment: Not fixed as of XF 3.0.0.446417... man this sucks!

Comment: Not fixed in XF 4.0 latest stable release

Comment: It's 2022. XF5. Still not fixed. LMAO

Comment: is there any fix ?

Answer (score 3):

Possible workaround would be to override *OnCurrentPageChanged* in your TabbedPage.

```
protected override void OnCurrentPageChanged()
{
    base.OnCurrentPageChanged();

    if ( CurrentPage is YourContentPage page)
    {
        page.YourCustomCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

On the main TabbedPage, after you've added child pages, setting the CurrentPage property to null should fix the problem.

Comment: @Shockwaver, Actually it does fix the problem. Don't know why it didn't work in your case. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/318378#Comment_318378

Comment: This addresses the previous bug of the first page's `OnAppearing` firing twice.  Does not fix all pages' `OnAppearing`s firing when the app starts.